# Proof using boolean algebra properties

Tags: proof-writing, boolean-algebra

I need to prove that

$$ x + y = y ~~~\iff~~~ xy = x $$

also need to prove that:

$$ x + y = x ~~~->~~~ x + not(y) = 1 $$

Using algebra boolean properties.

But I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Hint: from $x+y=y$, multiply both sides by $x$, then show the left hand side is equal to $x$

Comment: Thanks that's correct

Comment: This isn't true because if $x+y = y$, then $x + xy = xy$ and so $x=0$. The right condition is $x\lor y = y$ or equivalently $x+y + xy = y$

Comment: Sorry, our teacher uses "+" symbol as an OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a useful principle for the first problem:

**Absorption**

$x + xy = x$

$x(x+y) = x$

Applied to your problem 1, going from left to right:

Assume $x + y = y$.  Then $xy = x(x+y) = x$

Can you go from right to left?

For the second problem, use:

**Complement**

$x + x' = 1$

$xx'=0$

and

**Annihilation**

$x + 1 = 1$

$x0=0$

Comment: I can figure out the first one. But not the second problem. any help please?

Comment: Fill in $x+y$ for $x$ in $x +y'$ and see if you can simplify the result to $1$.  If parentheses are a conrn, you may also need Association to change parnetheses.